# Rest API consumption without using a response bean

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to consume a rest service which returning bunch of values. 
The bean look like follows.

```
Class Customer{
    Name, Address, Age ---etc // Almost 200 fields are there. Including reference to many objects as well. So it is very hard to create a bean for accepting the response.
}
```

Is there any alternative way to consume the response.

`Customer customer = restTemplate.getForObject(http://testurl);`

This is not I need. I need any other way to consume the service without creating the bean.

Using Spring Boot,Java 8

Comment: Please add some more info, like what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You probably might want to try to get JSONObject on your client side if you don't want to create a heavyweight DTO. Something along the lines:

```
String str = restTemplate.getForObject("http://testurl", String.class);
JSONObject myCustomer = new JSONObject(str);
String name = myCustomer.getString("name");
JSONObject address = myCustomer.getJSONObject("address"); // if address is a composite object with city, street, etc...
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved my time!

Comment: How can we access rest api secured with jwt?

Comment: OAuth2RestTemplate? Like in this example: https://gist.github.com/cjstehno/4fcc88f9266ed4ae268c#file-resttemplatetest-java . Afaik, jwt is a token format, so I suppose that by "secured with jwt" you mean oauth with jwt tokens. Anyway, that's a different question, probably already answered on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the response in a JSON format and use JSONObject class to extract the data.
Example:

```
String response = restTemplate.getJSONObject(http://testurl);
JSONObject params = new JSONObject(response);
if(params.has("Name"))
String customerName = params.getString("Name");
```